# How to create delete trigger in SQL on deletion of one record from child table updates the records count in parent table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created two tables .First is of magzine

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Magzine](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](350) NULL,
[MagzineType] [int] NOT NULL,
[TotalPages] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Active] [bit] NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tblMagzine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

which has a column name TotalPages which holds for the count of total pages in the magzine

and here is the MagzinePage Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MagzinePage](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MagzineID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[SubTitle] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Photo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsMapped] [bit] NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

I have created a trigger on the insertion of data in magzinePage table which can take care of the total number of records inserted in the table against an ID
 here is the Trigger

```
Alter TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[MagzinePage] 
    FOR INSERT

    AS
    Declare @MagzineID int;
    Declare @TotalPages int;
    Set @MagzineID= (Select Top 1 MagzineID From MagzinePage Order By ID Desc)
    Set @TotalPages =  (Select Count(MagzineID) from MagzinePage Where MagzineID=@MagzineID Group By MagzinePage.MagzineID) 

        Update Magzine Set TotalPages=@TotalPages Where ID= @MagzineID

        PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
    GO
```

Now I want to create a trigger for the purpose that can help decrement the total number of pages in the Magzine table whenever a record from the magzinePage table is deleted.

kindly do me favour to figure a way out for that.
Thanks.

Comment: Your current insert trigger is broken - a single `insert` could create rows for multiple magazines, but your trigger will only update one. Also, why do you think you need to store the count? If you perform the count during data retrieval (e.g. `SELECT`), it will always be correct.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbelieve 
I believe that this trigger is working fine and I need the count because i need to show a grid having all the details about the magzine.If i go with retrieving data every time than it might take long .What you suggest?

Comment: I've added a section to the end of my answer showing why your trigger is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an indexed view that will maintain the count up to date for you all the time:

```
create view dbo.vwMagzinePageCount 
with schemabinding
as
select [MagzineID], count_big(*) as TotalPages
from dbo.[MagzinePage]
group by [MagzineID];
go

create unique clustered index cdxMagzinePageCount 
    on dbo.vwMagzinePageCount (MagzineID);
go
```

I've kept your spelling of 'Magzine'. This is much better than a trigger from many points of view (correctness, performance etc). the engine will maintain this count up-to-date on *any* operation. Remove the TotalPages column from the Magzine table.

Comment: At last I got the solution with the Linq query ..I love that..
Thanks to all who gave me feedback.
Here is my Query


`public int getTotalPages(int magId)
 {
  using (SeekDataContextDataContext dc = new SeekDataContextDataContext())
     {
   return dc.MagzinePages.Where(p => p.MagzineID == magId).Select(p => p.ID).Count();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

If you do **need** to store the count, for whatever reason, have you considered getting SQL Server to do the work for you? If you remove `TotalPages` from your first table, and define this view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MagzineWithPages
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    select m.ID,Name,MagzineType,COUNT_BIG(*) as TotalPages,m.DateCreated,m.Active
    from
        dbo.Magzine m
            inner join
        dbo.MagzinePage mp
            on
                m.ID = mp.MagzineID
    group by
        m.ID,Name,MagzineType,m.DateCreated,m.Active
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MagzineWithPages on MagzineWithPages (ID)
```

Then the `COUNT()` will be automatically updated as page rows are added and removed. This also has the benefit that you might wish to update this definition, to e.g. ignore pages where `Active` is 0.

---

Why your trigger *is* broken - run an INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MagzinePage]([MagzineID],[DateCreated],[CreatedBy],[Active]) VALUES
(1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Me',1),
(2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'Me also',1)
```

The `TOP 1 MagzineID` from that table will now be either `1` or `2`. You'll run the update for one of those, and miss the other one.

---

If you really want to keep it in the original table (I'd strongly advise against it, by if your insistent):

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_MagzinePage on dbo.MagzinePage
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

;with Deltas as (
    select MagzineID,COUNT(*) as Cnt,0 as Del from inserted group by MagzineID
    union all
    select MagzineID,COUNT(*),1 from deleted group by MagzineID
), Merged as (
    select MagzineID,SUM(CASE WHEN Del=0 then Cnt ELSE -Cnt END) as Net
)
update m set TotalPages = TotalPages + Net
from Magzine m
inner join
Merged mm
on
    m.MagzineID = mm.MagzineID
```

Should do it as a single trigger (scrap your existing one), and properly copes with multiple rows in inserts, and with updates changing `MagzineID` and a whole host of other issues.

Comment: I can not remove the totalpages count from it because I am binding the total count on gridview using this table page.
I just need  a trigger that can do the trick for me here because right now i am in the middle of project and cannot change the structure,otherwise its gonna be messy.I hope you understand.